# ANTLR (v4) Arbitrary Rule Ordering

Tags: c#, parsing, antlr

I'm parsing a JSON-like structure that looks something like this:

```
items {
    item {
        name : 'Name',
        value : 'abc',
        type : String
    }
}
```

The parser rule for `item` might look like this:

```
item
    : name ',' value ',' type // I want these to be able to be in any order
    ;
name
    : NAME ':' Str
    ;
value
    : VALUE ':' atom
    ;
type
    : TYPE ':' data_type
    ;
```

How would I write the `item` rule such that the order of the key : value pairs is unimportant, and the parser would only check for the **presence** of the rule? That is, `value` could come before `name`, etc.

**EDIT**

I should clarify that I know I could do this:

```
item
    : item_item*
    ;
item_item
    : name
    | value
    | type
    ;
```

But the problem with that is that the `item` rule needs to limit each rule to only one instance. Using this technique, I could end up with any number of `name` rules, for example.

Answer (score 2):

*The naive brute force approach would be to solve the problem in syntactic analysis (**avoid this**):*

```
item
  : name ',' value ',' type
  | name ',' type ',' value
  | type ',' name ',' value
  | ...
  ;
```

*This leeds to a large parser spec and unmaintainable visitor/listener code.*

**Better:**
Use a simple parser rule and a semantic predicate to validate:

```
item
  : i+=item_item ',' i+=item_item ',' i+=item_item  {containsNVT($i)}?
  ;
item_item
  : name
  | value
  | type
  ;
```

You can place the code to validate that all three items are specified `containsNVT($i)` inline or in a parser super class.